# Sending a json using SQS and posting it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, string, amazon-sqs

I'm putting a json object / string (tried both) into a SQS queue - and I'm trying to post it as a payload in the lambda function that is triggered when the SQS has a new item in it.

My problem is the json comes out on the other end with additional \ (back slashes) added to every " I have, json object or string.

This is an example of how of a partial json I added to the SQS as plain string (which is the requirment) comes out on the other end:

```
"{\"properties\":{\"colorIconValue\":\"Other\",\"description\":\"According to media reports on Saturday, 26 January,
```

While the text looks like that when it enters the queue:

```
{"properties": {"colorIconValue": "Other","description": "International media r
```

Code for adding the json to the queue is from AWS blueprint:

```
    console.log("plain text" + incident_report);
                         var params = {
                            MessageBody: incident_report,
                            QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL
                        };
                        //write to SQS
                        sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
                          if(err) {
                            console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
                            context.done('error', "ERROR Put SQS");  // ERROR with message
                          }else{
                            //console.log('data:',data.MessageId);
                            context.done(null,'');  // SUCCESS 
                          }
                        });
```

I've tried adding the payload as JSON object and JSON.stringfy() it but I got the same result... which can't be posted later on (http post).

Answer (score 4):

Use `JSON.parse()` with your received SQS message. For example:

```
sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // Parse your data to received string to json
  const jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.Records[0].body);
});
```

This should save in `jsonObject` an object like the one you want.